# Adding List View Web part by Powershell and via GUI hasn't same View

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

Following is a part of my Powershell Script which creates a Discussion Board List and tries to add it to a default.aspx page. the problem is when I add default view to the code (marked as *) it generate this exception:"Exception calling "AddWebPart" with "3" argument(s): "The specified view is invalid." If I delete this line of code it works but the discussion board has a different view which contains only the title of the objects. However when I go to edit page and choose to add the list as a web part it works and has the threaded or unthreaded view which is right.

```
  $listName = "RIR Diskussion Forum"

  $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DiscussionBoard

  $web.Lists.Add($listName, "Riksrevisonens diskussions forum", [int]$listTemplate)

  $webPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl,  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$ListViewWebPart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart
$ListViewWebPart.Title = "Diskussion Forum"
$ListViewWebPart.ListName = ($list.ID).ToString("B").ToUpper()
$ListViewWebPart.ViewGuid = ($list.DefaultView.ID).ToString("B").ToUpper()  *
$ListViewWebPart.ZoneID = "Left"
$ListViewWebPart.ChromeType = "Default"

$ListViewWebPart.TitleUrl = $list.DefaultViewUrl
$ListViewWebPart.WebId = $list.ParentWeb.ID

$webPartManager.AddWebPart($ListViewWebPart, "Left", "0")
```

I need to add the List as a web part to the page by Powershell and make it to have same view as when you add it by GUI. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Medes,

first of all, in your example when *Discussion Board* instance is created,
the line that gets instance of newly created Discussion Board is missing, so i believe you need to add it after line

```
$web.Lists.Add($listName, "Riksrevisonens diskussions forum", [int]$listTemplate)
```

like this one

```
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
```

And the last one, when you add Discussion Board using GUI, it actually is **instantiated using [XsltListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart.aspx) and not [ListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.aspx)**.
So if you change the line where web part is created with this one:

```
$ListViewWebPart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
```

it would *add Discussion Board on page as you expect it to*.

Hope this helps,

Vadim

Comment: thank you very much. Generally Is there a way to find out which type of web parts GUI adds to a page?

Comment: sure, for example, if you open the page in Maintenance Mode. To open page in this mode just append the "?contents=1" to your page url. For more details please see here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tadd/archive/2009/03/27/contents-1.aspx)